# Java Spring Boot Docker project with MySQL - All values saved as null in the database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, docker

I want my project to create a table and it is saved in mysql, the problem is that when saving all values are null

I am being forced to write something else, but I do not know what to add, this project can be done through mvc by writing to the save post update delete controllers, I would do this after it would be possible to solve the problem that has arisen now

i use docker
docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
```

application.yaml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cimpoiesu
    username: root
    password: example
  jpa:
    showSql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
```

pom.xml

```
...
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>            
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

main class

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
   }

   @Bean
   CommandLineRunner runner(StudentRepository repository) {
      return args -> {
         Address address = new Address(
               "Z",
               "X",
               "C"
         );
         Student student = new Student(
               "Danila",
               "Cimpoiesu",
               "danila.cimpoiesu@mail.ru",
               Gender.MALE,
               address,
               List.of("Computer science"),
               BigDecimal.TEN,
               LocalDateTime.now()
         );

         repository.save(student);
      };
   }
}
```

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends
        JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
}
```

```
package com.example.demo;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import lombok.Data;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private Gender gender;
    private Address address;
    private List<String> favouriteSubject;
    private BigDecimal totalSpentInBooks;
    private LocalDateTime created;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String firstname, String lastname, String email, Gender gender, Address address, List<String> favouriteSubject, BigDecimal totalSpentInBooks, LocalDateTime created) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.address = address;
        this.favouriteSubject = favouriteSubject;
        this.totalSpentInBooks = totalSpentInBooks;
        this.created = created;
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.demo;

import jakarta.persistence.Embeddable;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class Address {
    private String country;
    private String city;
    private String postCode;
}
```

```
package com.example.demo;

public enum Gender {
    MALE, FEMALE
}
```

[image]

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.5)

2023-05-30T15:54:04.647+03:00  INFO 9896 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 19 with PID 9896 (C:\Users\jesus\Desktop\plack\target\classes started by jesus in C:\Users\jesus\Desktop\plack)
2023-05-30T15:54:04.656+03:00  INFO 9896 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-05-30T15:54:06.140+03:00  INFO 9896 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-05-30T15:54:06.324+03:00  INFO 9896 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 158 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-05-30T15:54:07.720+03:00  INFO 9896 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-05-30T15:54:07.737+03:00  INFO 9896 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-05-30T15:54:07.738+03:00  INFO 9896 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.7]
2023-05-30T15:54:07.918+03:00  INFO 9896 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-05-30T15:54:07.921+03:00  INFO 9896 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3113 ms
2023-05-30T15:54:08.298+03:00  INFO 9896 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-05-30T15:54:08.423+03:00  INFO 9896 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
2023-05-30T15:54:08.998+03:00  INFO 9896 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-05-30T15:54:09.740+03:00  INFO 9896 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@55adcf9e
2023-05-30T15:54:09.745+03:00  INFO 9896 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-05-30T15:54:09.893+03:00  INFO 9896 --- [           main] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Hibernate: drop table if exists student
Hibernate: create table student (id bigint not null auto_increment, city varchar(255), country varchar(255), post_code varchar(255), created datetime(6), email varchar(255), favourite_subject varbinary(255), firstname varchar(255), gender smallint, lastname varchar(255), total_spent_in_books decimal(38,2), primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
2023-05-30T15:54:11.908+03:00  INFO 9896 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-05-30T15:54:11.923+03:00  INFO 9896 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-05-30T15:54:12.463+03:00  WARN 9896 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-05-30T15:54:13.171+03:00  INFO 9896 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-05-30T15:54:13.187+03:00  INFO 9896 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 9.612 seconds (process running for 10.486)
Hibernate: insert into student (city, country, post_code, created, email, favourite_subject, firstname, gender, lastname, total_spent_in_books) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

I have done a project using mongodb before and it worked and I want to redo it for mysql

Comment: Are you sure the values are actually null, because it looks more like to me that the screen shot show that the definition of your table ALLOWS null values, rather than you showing any examples of data.

Comment: Oh really, thanks, I didn't think about it

Answer (score 0):

Those NULL in the table are indicating that the columns are nullable. Compare id bigint **not null**

```
Hibernate: create table student (id bigint not null auto_increment, city varchar(255), country varchar(255), post_code varchar(255), created datetime(6), email varchar(255), favourite_subject varbinary(255), firstname varchar(255), gender smallint, lastname varchar(255), total_spent_in_books decimal(38,2), primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
```

To see what has been added to the db add the following to your code after          `repository.save(student);`

```
    repository.findAll().stream().forEach(student -> System.out.println(student));
```

To prevent the DB accepting nulls to a column add the following annotation to the field:

```
@Column(nullable = false)
```